# function DATE() type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I can't make this work

```
Dim StrtD As Long, EndD As Long
Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
Dim myVar As Variant
Dim stringaAppoggio As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settimana")
    StartDate = .TextBox1.Value
    EndDate = .TextBox2.Value
End With

StrtD = Month(StartDate)
EndD = StrtD + DateDiff("m", StartDate, EndDate)
yearData = year(StartDate)
arr4 = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(yearData,ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & "),1), ""[$-0410]mmmm yyyy"")"))

For Each myVar In arr4

stringaAppoggio = myVar
```

StartDate is **"01/01/2020"** 
EndDate is **"01/10/2020"**

The error is **stringaAppoggio = myVar**

> type mismatch

I think the error is **yearData** in **Application.Transpose** because if I put **2020** it works!

Thank you

Comment: Let's start at declaring and assigning the correct values. *Where* and *how* do you assign your `StartDate` and `EndDate` ***before*** you use them for `StrtD` and your other variables?

Comment: I take them from my TextBox1.Value and TextBox2.Value

Comment: I tried to declare yearData as **Integer** , **Variant**, **String**, **Date** but none of these had worked

Comment: I still got a feeling you are leaving out some relevant information. How does your code even compile > `Application.Transpose(.Evaluate` would not compile because of a unqualified `.Evaluate`. Also, I assume your goal is to return an array of values? Can you elaborate? Small sidenote, you can transpose within the formula!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things going wrong for you here:

- Your code should not even compile in the first place, because (with the information you have shown) `Application.Transpose(.Evaluate` holds a unqualified `.Evaluate` method.
- As I told you yesterday, `Debug.Print` is a great way of checking if what you intended to write, actually gets written in the `.Evaluate`. Currently you are using `yeardata` wrong within the formula. It's a variable holding a string value! Don't get confused with thinking that writing this word within another string automatically picks up you meant to use the variable.
- To `TRANSPOSE` values from a worksheet into a 1D-array, you can do so directly through your formula.
- I just assume your code sample above isn't complete and includes a `Next` below `stringaAppoggio = myVar`

Considering the above, I think your code can be rewritten to something like:

```
arr4 = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(TEXT(DATE(" & yearData & ",ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & "),1), ""[$-0410]mmmm yyyy""))")
```

Answer (score 1):

`yeardata` variable is not <s>evaluated</s> passed correctly to your string formula. You need to concatenate it directly into your formula string like what you did in `StrtD` and `EndD` variables. Try:

```
arr4 = Application.Transpose(.Evaluate("TEXT(DATE(" & yearData & _
       ",ROW(" & StrtD & ":" & EndD & "),1), ""[$-0410]mmmm yyyy"")"))
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! What do you mean is not evaluated correctly? Why I need to concatenate it, if I only put the result of **yeardata** in the function?

Comment: Was writing kind of the same answer =). The one thing is the unqualified `.Evaluate`. Code shouldn't even compile. @TheMite, you need to concatenate different pieces of information into a full string to `Evaluate`. The variable holds a string and isn't the string itself to be used. Therefor `Debug.Print` is a great way of telling you if what you wanted actually gets evaluated.